# Select device monodroid manager doesn't see already running emulator image

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android

Sometimes, when I start debugging of android application in `Visual Studio 2012` I can't see emulator image in select device window:

[image]

but emulator is already running:

[image]

The thing is that the problem is not in my application code or project settings because when i select `Start emulator image`, and new android virtual device is running, my application deploys successfully and is running correctly on **NEW** virtual device, **BUT** it takes a lot of time to load this new virtual device image and deploy application on it. Why doesn't Select device manages see already running virtual device image?

P.S. I deploy the simplest hello world activity, which is created by default when I start new Android Application project in `Visual Studio 2012`

Comment: Sometimes it bothers me too. Close VS 2012 and open it again while keep emulator running. This trick always solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens frequently.

From my informal experience... It seems sometimes to be related to VS and MonoDroid - but mostly it seems down to the Android SDK.

As the comment above suggests, switching VS off and on again can sometimes help.

Other things that can help are:

- update to the latest version of Mono for Android - the Monkeys at Xamarin have added a Refresh button to the display
- try using the command line adb tool in the SDK. This Android Debug Bridge includes kill-server and start-server switches - using these allows you to refresh the Android SDK's connections to devices.

For more on adb, see http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-adb-quick-guide/ and http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html - it's a useful tool to know

If you do identify any clear bug in Mono for Android's connectivity, then please report it on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com